# Derivative of the $p\to q$ norm

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, reference-request, optimization, matrix-calculus

Consider the $p\to q$ norm for a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ where

$$
\|A\|_{p\to q} = \max_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\}} \frac{\|Ax\|_q}{\|x\|_p}
$$

(defined as in https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.07425)

I'm interested in the special case when $p = 2$ and $q=1$. Is the subgradient of the function $f(A) = \|A\|_{2\to 1}$ known?